# Update custom MasterPage for Layouts application page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to create a application page under _Layouts folder (using Visual studio 2010). It works perfect with default MasterpPage. But if I try to update DynamicMasterPageFile property to my custom masterpage, it gives me error.

I have created a Blank Masterpage, but still  I am not able to associate the masterpage with my application page ( under _Layouts folder).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to update MasterPageFile property to new masterpage. This works perfectly fine in one of my application pages.

`<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/MCPT/Collaboration.Master" Inherits="Collaboration.Tool.ApplicationPages.ChangePassword" EnableViewState="true" EnableViewStateMac="true"%>`